# Which coding language is used in comptel eventlink and instantklink?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, billing, telecommunication, mobile-ad-mediation

I am mediation developer, I want to know about which languages are used in telecommunication for mediation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comptel Eventlink is quite a sophisticated mediation solution and it has multiple components and multiple ways to configure and extend it.

It includes custom environments to extend and build operator specific functionality, for example the Business Logic Tool which provides a graphical UI to build business logic.

There are also many different data aggregation, filtering etc rules which can be configured.

So, a lot of the skills you would need to work with a solution like this will be specific to the solution itself. There does not seem to be many courses offered at this time although you may find some in the more general Nokia courses as Nokia now owns Comptel. There also seems to be a good collection of Comptel manual online if you search in places like kupdf.net.

Comment: Do they use any specific language like java or python for configuring nodes.Currently I am using mediation zone software.I want to know about comptel, they do have their specific langauge for configuration of nodes?

Comment: They steer people towards the UI for configuring although I am sure there are scripted options also: From a quick look its some of the docs on the web: 'The Comptel EventLink system is configured through EventLink User Interface, which can also be used for monitoring the whole system, viewing audit information on the data processing and creating reports about the events handled by Comptel EventLink.'

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perl, C, C++ and Comptel's Business Logic Tool to program mediation based on EventLink.

Answer (score 0):

when I worked for Comptel in 2004 their solution where done on the Unix/Linux C-Shell language (Csh). A C like programming language with Oracle DB under.